# Host 2 Websites 1 on IIS with 80 Port and 1 on Xampp 8081 port

Tags: windows, dns, xampp, port, vhosts

I am having a website first.com which is deployed on a windows server with ip like (11.111.111.11) using 80 port (DNS is pointed on first.com of host server), Now I have installed Xampp and run on 8081 port and deployed code which can be accessed using ip 11.111.111.11:8081/second, what I have to do is another domain second.com to point this second folder of xampp so second.com is equals to 11.111.111.11:8081/second, I have changed DNS of second.com  to host DNS of first.com as it is done for this domain.

And changed my vhost of xampp like

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName www.second.com
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/second">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I am hitting this second.com it points the same website of first.com but when I hit second.com:8081/second it points to the new website which logically is working fine, now I want that second.com should open the new website without showing any port/folder.
I believe it is Possible,  Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe enabled the virtual host on the xampp,

then you can do the domains pointed to same port by editing the file /httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/website_a
   ServerName www.website_a.com
   ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website_a/error_log"
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/website_b
 ServerName www.website_b.com
 ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/htdocs/website_b/error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to know more some reference, here is one for you:

https://github.com/oliguo/Server-Deployment/blob/master/XAMPP.md